# want delimited data from file which has headers footers,for data crunching to do performance analysis

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file which has header and footers and data is over multiple iteration (with headers and footers), I want to delimit the data and don't want headers footers. My objective is to data crunching in order to do performance analysis, its just that parsing piece is not going fine.

Data in file:

```
   09:31:56 12/13/11 r/w I/O per second KBytes per sec  Svt ms     IOSz KB     
              VVname      Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg  Max Cur Avg   Cur   Avg Qlen
               admin   r    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0 0.0   0.0   0.0    -
               admin   w   17   17   17   68   68   68 0.2 0.2   4.1   4.1    -
               admin   t   17   17   17   68   68   68 0.2 0.2   4.1   4.1    0
 z0001_app0136_s.254   r    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0 0.0   0.0   0.0    -
 z0001_app0136_s.254   w    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0 0.0   0.0   0.0    -
 z0001_app0136_s.254   t    0    0    0    0    0    0 0.0 0.0   0.0   0.0    0
....................
....................

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Footer            394   r   87   87      4354 4354      2.7 2.7  49.9  49.9    -
  Footer            394   w  126  126       906  906      0.1 0.1   7.2   7.2    -
  Footer            394   t  213  213      5260 5260      1.2 1.2  24.7  24.7    0
   09:32:57 12/13/11 r/w I/O per second KBytes per sec    Svt ms     IOSz KB     
              VVname      Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg  Max  Cur  Avg   Cur   Avg Qlen
               admin   r    0    0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    -
               admin   w   32   24   32  130   99  130  0.2  0.2   4.1   4.1    -
               admin   t   32   24   32  130   99  130  0.2  0.2   4.1   4.1    0
 z0001_app0136_s.254   r    0    0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    -
 z0001_app0136_s.254   w    0    0    0    0    0    0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0    -
```

And data over in file goes over again and again.

Comment: What constitutes a header and what constitutes a footer? Would you be able to provide example output? Are your headers and footers always the same number of lines long?

Comment: Does your file footer has the string 'footer' with it ? If so then try  #grep ' [rtw] ' logfilename | grep -iv footer

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to cleaning up data like that is to use grep, either to select the data you want or to exclude the data you don't want.  In this case, it looks like all the desired lines have a letter (r, t, or w) with a space on each side, and none of the undesired lines have that.  (*Edit:* Footer lines were added to question somewhat later, so `grep -v` commands have been added to exclude footers.)

If the data is in file d, you would say:

```
grep ' [rtw] ' d | grep -v Footer
```

and that will select the data lines but not the headers, footers, or blank lines.  To make a file called t with the data, say:

```
grep ' [rtw] ' d | grep -v Footer > t
```

If the actual data (vs. what appeared in question) uses tabs or whitespace other than blanks, then use `'[[:space:]][rtw][[:space:]]'` as the search string instead of `' [rtw] '`.  Also, grep is case-sensitive when -i isn't used.  If the term to exclude occurs both ways (sometimes in upper, sometimes in lower case) use `-iv` instead of `-v` for the grep options:

```
grep '[[:space:]][rtw][[:space:]]' d  | grep -iv footer > t
```

Comment: well the footers also have rtw so that wont help me, I guess, unless you correct me on that.

Comment: @Robi, the regex shown selects only the data lines, none of the headers/footers, because `[rtw]` stands for one of the letters r, t, or w, and the pattern `' [rtw] '` stands for space, one of the r-t-w letters, and another space.  Try it out.

Comment: I tried it out, I get footors in the output as footers also gives total of (reads writes totals).

Comment: I think what you telling is , footer is also a block of data which you don't need. Is the footer a fixed size ? Say like last 10 lines ?

Comment: lets say, I have data for reads writes and combination or (read and writes which is total) for 50 volumes, in the footer I get the average of reads, writes and totals. so i have (r, w, t) in footer too. so grep ' [rtw] ' doesnot solves the purpose..

Answer (score 0):

You should really format your input to include an adequate amount of sample data. Also, you should add some expected output to show what you are trying to accomplish. You may also like to consider reading and replying to the comments under your question.

That said, this line of `GNU awk`, *may* help you:

```
awk '$1 !~ /^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/ && $1 != "VVname" && $1 != "Footer"' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# file: 12523967.sh
# Needs at least bash version 3.x

: ${DEBUG:=0}
: ${LOGFILE:="./12523967-data.log"}

TOKENS="VVname Flag Cur_IO_s Avg_IO_s Max_IO_s Cur_KB_s Avg_KB_s Max_KB_s Cur_Svt_ms Avg_Svt_ms Cur_IOSz_KB Avg_IOSz_KB Qlen"
DREGEX="^[[:digit:]]{2}:.*$"

while IFS=, read $TOKENS; do
    ## Skip entry if empty, or contains 'Footer' or 'Timestamp' or 'VVname'
    if [[ -z $VVname || $VVname =~ $DREGEX || $VVname =~ VVname || $VVname =~ Footer ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    [[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]] && printf "%s %s %s %s %s %s\n" \
                "$VVname $Flag" \
                "$Cur_IO_s $Avg_IO_s $Max_IO_s" \
                "$Cur_KB_s $Avg_KB_s $Max_KB_s" \
                "$Cur_Svt_ms $Avg_Svt_ms" \
                "$Cur_IOSz_KB $Avg_IOSz_KB" \
                "$Qlen"

    # [...] Do whatever you have to do with the named entries

done < <(sed -e 's/^ *//g;s/  */,/g;s/^[\.-]*//g;' $LOGFILE)
```

Using your example (including '...' and '---' lines, since I wasn't quite sure if they form part of your log file output), a call with `DEBUG=1` prints out the parsed lines by their field names:

```
$ DEBUG=1 ./12523967-parse.sh 
    admin r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
    admin w 17 17 17 68 68 68 0.2 0.2 4.1 4.1  -
    admin t 17 17 17 68 68 68 0.2 0.2 4.1 4.1  0
    z0001_app0136_s.254 r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
    z0001_app0136_s.254 w 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
    z0001_app0136_s.254 t 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  0
    admin r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
    admin w 32 24 32 130 99 130 0.2 0.2 4.1 4.1  -
    admin t 32 24 32 130 99 130 0.2 0.2 4.1 4.1  0
    z0001_app0136_s.254 r 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
    z0001_app0136_s.254 w 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0  -
```